# Prevent wildcard in htaccess 301 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have setup a htaccess 301 redirect to redirect an indexed page to a new page, however this is also acting as a wildcard redirect for child pages which I do no what to happen.

**Old structure**

- example.com/faq
- example.com/faq/question-1
- example.com/faq/question-2
- etc etc

**New structure**

- example.com/faqs
- example.com/faq/question-1
- example.com/faq/question-2
- etc etc

htaccess redirect in place :

```
Redirect 301 /faq/ https://example.com/faqs/
```

This is working with no issues to send /faq to /faqs however it is also sending /faq/* to /faqs/* which I do not want to happen.

For example going to *example.com/faq/question-1* causes a to many redirects error and finally lands on *example.com/faqs/question-1*

Is there anything i can add to the single redirect line to prevent this happening, or is their a more complex use of RewriteRule I could use instead. Research into the matter initially seem to confirm that this should/would happen, and if it does what can be added to prevent it. After a prompt to the apache docs I can see why they would redirect as a wildcard.

Comment: _“Research into the matter doesn't seem to confirm that this should/would happen”_ – https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect explicitly explains, that it behaves this way: _“Then any request **beginning with** URL-path will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. **Additional path information beyond the matched URL-path will be appended to the target URL.**”_ Use `RedirectMatch` instead, that works based on regular expressions, so with a pattern _anchored_ at the start and finish, you can force a redirect only on an exact match.

Comment: That's fair - all of the results I was getting on any searches weren't coming up with the apache docs - will edit question. I have actually looked at using RedirectMatch instead, however I am still getting the same results with different expressions - do you have an example of an expression which will redirect the parent page, but not the child ones?

Comment: 301 redirects get cached by browsers, so first of all you need to make sure you’re not getting fooled by that now ;-) `^/faq/$` should basically do the job here.

Comment: Thank you - this worked a charm - was clearing all caches before, but hadn't come across your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

After suggests from CBroe an implementation of using **RedirectMatch** worked.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/faq/$ https://example.com/faqs
```

This now redirects /faq to /faqs, however doesn't redirect /faq/question-1 to /faqs/question-1 etc